# Is there a way to find the transaction count on a sql table?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to find out the count of inserts, updates and deletes on a SQL tables in a given day or today? All counts together is fine too, if individual counts are not possible. Is there a way to find this stats information in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: This article may help: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/how-are-per-column-modification-counts-tracked/

Comment: That article is a good info. Can we actually find the count per day?

Comment: going back historically you probably couldn't get a daily count but going forward you could. track the mod count daily and your delta would be daily changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx) DMF.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats(DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'schema.table'), NULL, NULL);
```

There is *a lot* of very interesting and useful info in that DMF, but with respect to this particular question, the following columns should have what you are looking for:

> **leaf_insert_count** -- bigint -- Cumulative count of leaf-level inserts.
>
> **leaf_delete_count** -- bigint -- Cumulative count of leaf-level deletes. leaf_delete_count is only incremented for deleted records that are not marked as ghost first. For deleted records that are ghosted first, leaf_ghost_count is incremented instead.
>
> **leaf_update_count** -- bigint -- Cumulative count of leaf-level updates.

It won't show history, so take a sample once per day. And like all DMVs and DMFs, it probably gets recent upon service restart.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an index on the table you can get the stats from that index. Some information about the [dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx).

TotalWrites column 
Number of updates by user queries. This includes Insert, Delete and Updates representing number
of operations done not the actual rows affected. For example, if you delete 1000 rows in one statement,this count will increment by 1

The counters are initialized to empty whenever the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is started.

In addition, whenever a database is detached or is shut down
all rows associated with the database are removed. This means that
the information provided when the server first boots up will not reflect
your workload.

```
select [I].[name] AS [IndexName], 
[IUS].[user_updates] AS [TotalUpdates]
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS IUS WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS I WITH (NOLOCK)
ON [IUS].[object_id] = [I].[object_id]
AND [IUS].[index_id] =  [I].[index_id]
Where database_id = DB_ID()
and IUS.object_id=object_id('tablename')
```